# SDL Window won't change colors (C++)

Tags: c++, window, sdl, sdl-2

Question:
First off, I'm very new to C++ so I'm just starting out. One of the exercises I'm currently on is having me create a "Particle Explosion" as you can see in the window title then have it flash different colors as you can see in the main.cpp.

My problem:
Whenever I run it in VS2015 I get my console to open, the window opens, but it doesn't flash any colors, it just stays white. Everything seems to be working just fine and it doesn't freeze or have any errors. Just. No. Colors.

Does anyone see an error I'm making? Once I created it I compared it to the exercise, but everything seems to be 100% exactly the same.

I'm on W7, VS2015 and using SDL2 lib.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Screen.h"
#include <math.h>
#undef main

using namespace std;
using namespace caveofprogramming;


int main() {

    Screen screen;
    if (screen.init() == false) {
        cout << "Error initialzing SDL." << endl;
    }

    while (true) {
        // Update particles

        // Draw Particles
        int elapsed = SDL_GetTicks();
        unsigned char green = (1 + sin(elapsed * 0.001)) * 128;
        unsigned char red = (1 + sin(elapsed * 0.002)) * 128;
        unsigned char blue = (1 + sin(elapsed * 0.003)) * 128;

        for (int y = 0; y < Screen::SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Screen::SCREEN_WIDTH; x++) {
                screen.setPixel(x, y, red, green, blue);

            }
        }

        //Draw the screen

        // Check for messages/events
        if (screen.processEvents() == false) {
            break;
        }
    }

    screen.close();

    return 0; // usually when your program runs ok it returns 0
}
```

**Screen.cpp**

```
    #include "Screen.h"
    #include <iostream>

    namespace caveofprogramming {

        Screen::Screen() :
            m_window(NULL), m_renderer(NULL), m_texture(NULL), m_buffer(NULL) {

        }

        bool Screen::init() {
            if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
                return false;
            }

            m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Particle Fire Explosion",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

            if (m_window == NULL) {
                SDL_Quit();
                return false;
            }

            m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
            m_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(m_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
                SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

            if (m_renderer == NULL) {
                SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
                SDL_Quit();
                return false;
            }

            if (m_texture == NULL) {
                SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_renderer);
                SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
                SDL_Quit();
                return false;
            }

            m_buffer = new Uint32[SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT];

            memset(m_buffer, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * sizeof(Uint32));

            return true;
        }

        void Screen::clear() {
            memset(m_buffer, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * sizeof(Uint32));
        }

        void Screen::setPixel(int x, int y, Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue) {

            if (x < 0 || x >= SCREEN_WIDTH || y < 0 || y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
                return;
            }

            Uint32 color = 0;

            color += red;
            color <<= 8;
            color += green;
            color <<= 8;
            color += blue;
            color <<= 8;
            color += 0xFF;

            m_buffer[(y * SCREEN_WIDTH) + x] = color;
        }

        void Screen::update() {
            SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture, NULL, m_buffer, SCREEN_WIDTH * sizeof(Uint32));
            SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer);
            SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, m_texture, NULL, NULL);
            SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer);
        }

        bool Screen::processEvents() {
            SDL_Event event;

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
                if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        void Screen::close() {
            delete[] m_buffer;
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_renderer);
            SDL_DestroyTexture(m_texture);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
            SDL_Quit();
        }
    }
```

**Screen.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
namespace caveofprogramming {


class Screen {
public:
    const static int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    const static int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

private:
    SDL_Window *m_window;
    SDL_Renderer *m_renderer;
    SDL_Texture *m_texture;
    Uint32 *m_buffer;

public:
    Screen();
    bool init();
    bool processEvents();
    void update();
    void clear();
    void setPixel(int x, int y, Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue);
    void close();
};

}
```

Comment: Your rendering is done inside `Screen::update()`, but it looks like it is never called.

Comment: That was it! Added 

//Draw the screen
screen.update();

Answer (score 0):

As Elderbug said, I just had to add the function to my object to render.

//Draw the screen
screen.update();

thanks!